# Definition 1.6 of Delaunay Triangulation - Curve and Surface Reconstruction

Tags: definition, computational-geometry

I'm reading the very first chapter of [Tamal K. Dey - Curva and Surface Reconstruction](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=v_OyHkgVnnUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=curve%20and%20surface%20reconstruction%20algorithms%20with%20mathematical%20analysis&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsyLXm4bHkAhXTh1wKHcvaA5wQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=curve%20and%20surface%20reconstruction%20algorithms%20with%20mathematical%20analysis&f=false).

There's a small notation issue I don't quite get in the following definition:

> **Definition 1.6** : The Delaunay Triangulation of $P$ is a simplicial complex
> $$
> \text{Del}\;P = \left\{ \sigma = \text{Conv}\;T : \bigcap_{p\in T \subset P} V_p \neq \emptyset \right\}
> $$

Here $V_p$ is a Voronoi cell. I'm not sure what $\text{Conv} \; T$ is supposed to be. If I go back the only place where I see such notation used is in the following:

> A simplex $\sigma' = \text{Conv} \; T$ for a nonempty subset $T \subset P$ is called a face of $\sigma$. $\sigma$ is a *k*-simplex and $P$ is a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^k$.

I'm tempted to think that $\text{Conv} \; T$ is a face of the $k$-simplex, but it there's no actual definition and I don't want to misunderstand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By '$\text{Conv}~T$', the author certainly mean the convex hull or convex combination. For k+1 point in dimension k, it is just a simplex (triangle in 2D, tetrahedron in 3D...)

The mathematical definition is described in the books with a sentence:

> In words, k+1 points in P form a Delaunay k-simplex if their Voronoi cells have nonempty intersection.

---

I however agree that both are difficult to understand, so I will explain it with my own words:

> If you can find a set of k+1 Voronoi cells that all intersect (every pair has an intersection), then the points associated with the Voronoi cells form a k-simplex (a triangle in 2D) of the Delaunay triangulation.

For example, in the following image, select 3 Voronoi cells at random. If they have at least a point in common, there is a triangle of the Delaunay triangulation that connects the points (called seeds, sites, or generators) of those same Voronoi cells.

[image: Voronoi-Delaunay]

Comment: I don't understand your definition, do you think you could put a picture maybe?